# Android app using webview - trigger device event or phone call

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an android app that uses the java webview.  I am wondering if there is a way to create a button or some kind of link within the app to trigger the device to call a specified number.  For example, I'm doing an app for a store, and I'd like to have a button that says Call store.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the href of your anchor tag point to a 'tel' URI should do the trick:

```
<a href="tel:1111111111">Call Us!</a>
```

If your WebView is using a custom WebViewClient, you may need to implement some special logic in 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading'.

See:

[Common Intents - Phone](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Phone)

[WebView - Handling Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation)

Comment: You can intercept any URL at the and trigger events within Java.  This opens up so many possiblities!  Very cool.